# overload operator [] c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to overload [], so I can do:

```
Arrayclass x = Arrayclass()

Someclass *sc = new Someclass();

x[12] = sc;
```

There is no problem with simple types like int, but there is a problem I see - what will happen with 12th "cell" of the Arrayclass? How can I call delete on it? e.g. something like:

```
delete x[12];
x[12] = sc;
```

Comment: `Arrayclass x;` is sufficient. What type do you want to store via the operator? Does the `x` own the data pointed to or is it owned elsewhere?

Comment: Practice using `std::vector<Someclass>` and `std::vector<Someclasss *>` to help you understand the issues.

Comment: Arrayclass holds pointers to Someclass

Comment: Next to consider is whether the class owns the resources held by the pointers or not.

Comment: yes it owns the resources. the whole overload thing is research. I saw std:HashMap do the same overload, but I was not able to figure out how it is done.

Comment: If it owns the resources, you should not delete the objects outside of the class. The class should delete the objects when they are erased.

Comment: this is the exact question :) but I can not figure out how to ask it

Comment: What you want looks like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Someclass>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `operator[]` to return a *reference* to the object. That will allow assigning.

```
Someclass& operator[](size_t i);
```

Unless the array class holds *pointers*, there's no need to call `delete` on an element, ever. If it holds pointers but never exposes them to the caller, it should handle all the necessary deletes by itself.

Comment: class holds pointers

Answer (score 0):

Not advisable, though, but you can do this:

```
Someclass*& Arrayclass operator[](size_t index);
```

You need consider few points:

- Is the same overload to be used for reading and writing?
- What about invalid index?

Answer (score 0):

You may have:

```
Someclass& Arrayclass operator[] (int index) {
  // ..
}
```

And you get a SomeClass object by reference when you call

```
x[12] = *sc; // allowed
```

but

```
delete x[12]; // not allowed, x[12] is an object, not a pointer
```

also risky even you expose pointer, i.e. don't do the following:

```
Someclass*& Arrayclass operator[] (int index) {
  // ..
}
```